# How to get topic message by time (similar to tf)?

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to be able to get a topic message by its time(stamp).
tf provides similar functunality for transformations, but is there any implementation for other topics?

For example I want to get the message on topic '/foo' that arrived 2 seconds ago.

Thanks, xaedes

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/163656/how-to-get-topic-message-by-time-(similar-to-tf)?/) by [xaedes](https://answers.ros.org/users/6307/xaedes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-05-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A message filter cache should be able to do that:
http://docs.ros.org/api/message_filters/html/c++/classmessage__filters_1_1Cache.html

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1